# Move user to a textchannel as soon as he has pressed a button

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a problem. I would like to move a user from one specific textchannel to another specific textchannel as soon as he has pressed a button.
Unfortunately I get an error.

```py
class MyView(discord.ui.View): # Create a class called MyView that subclasses discord.ui.View
    @discord.ui.button(label="->", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, emoji="") 
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        channel = interaction.guild.get_channel(os.getenv('CHANNEL_ID_SETUP2'))
        await discord.Member.move_to(channel)

@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True, ban_members=True) 
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send(view=MyView())
```

```py
TypeError: move_to() missing 1 required positional argument: 'channel'
```

Comment: What do you mean, move to textchannel? `move_to` only works with voice channels, no?

Comment: @Amadan Oh well? Thanks! I would like to move a user to a certain text channel, not voice channel.

Comment: You cannot move users to a text channel as it works just like a view, not functionality.

Comment: Text channels do not have membership. Or, another way to look at it, a user is simultaneously in all the text channels allowed to them. There is no function to "move to textchannel". What you want is to force the user to _display_ a different text channel; but there is no API for that. Best you can do, I believe, is display a channel link, allowing the user the option to switch by clicking on it.

Comment: @Amadan can a user jump to a certain message with that button? That is like moving or?

Comment: Dunno about a button. But I assume you can make a message with an embed that contains a link to a message URL.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because you're calling `move_to` on the **class name**, not an **instance**. Discord.py has no idea which member you want to move when you write `discord.Member.move_to()`, you need an **instance of the class**.

You mentioned wanting to move the person when they click on the button, so you can get their `Member` instance using `interaction.user`.

As for making a member see a message, that isn't like "moving". That's what happens when you click on a message's `jump_url`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How could a member jump to a message with `jump_url` when clicking a button ?

Comment: You could use a link button & use the `jump_url` as the link. Here's an official example: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/link.py