# After clicking the button the user should jump to a specific message in another text channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a problem. I have created a button, if the user presses this button the user should jump to a certain message in another text channel.
How do I do that? There is `jump_url` but how do I refer from the button to the messages and that the user jumps?

```py
class MyView(discord.ui.View): # Create a class called MyView that subclasses discord.ui.View
    @discord.ui.button(label="->", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, emoji="") 
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked the button!") # Send a message when the button is clicked
    # link to certian message

@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True, ban_members=True) 
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send(view=MyView())
```

Answer (score 0):

I already answered this question in your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74457319/move-user-to-a-textchannel-as-soon-as-he-has-pressed-a-button). There is a special type of button for links, and you can set the url to the `jump_url` of the message.

Other than that, you can send an embed with the link in it. If you don't want either of those then there's no other option.

Official example: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/link.py

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I also need this command `await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked the button!")` and the with that example it does not work

Comment: That's not possible (a Discord limitation). As I mentioned, if you want to send a message with the link in it then you can send an embed. Using buttons there's no way to do this.

Comment: Your example doesn't help much. It does not show how to jump from this button to a specific message in another text channel.

Comment: Yes it does? Just use the message's ``jump_url`` as the URL. It's an example, not a block of code with your exact use case that you can copy paste. You literally have to change **1** line.....